# how to remove blank text file from folder?

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, sed, grep

I have multiple text file around 2000 text file in folder. I want to remove those file which are blank file.

Comment: @jasonwryan Possibly, but is a file with whitespace a "blank file" here?

Comment: @Sparhawk FIIK: there is no actual detail in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, use the following command to identify all the empty files.

```
find -size 0
```

Then, to delete, run the following command.

```
find -size 0 -delete
```

N.B. this is recursive, i.e. descends into all sub-directories. If you only want to act on the current directory, add the following option.

```
-maxdepth 0
```